# Graduate Measure Theory Question: Differentiability/Integrability under weak conditions

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, continuity, lebesgue-measure, radon-nikodym

The following question is exercise 14.3 from section 14.8 in Real Analysis For Graduate Students (2nd Edition) by Richard Bass.

Suppose $f$ is a real-valued continuous function on $[0,1]$ and that $\varepsilon >0$. Prove that there exists a continuous function $g$ such that $g'(x)$ exists and equals $0$ for almost every x and 
$$
\sup_{x\in [0,1]}|f(x)-g(x)|<\varepsilon.
$$

What I think I know: The question gives me the weakest (point-wise) continuity on $f$ in $[0,1]$. Given only this information, I need to build up some kind of bulwark of mathematical theory proving the existence of the desired function of $g$, of which I do not believe I am capable. Or alternatively there may be some way to use Radon-Nikodym or Lebesgue decomposition to infer the conclusion. In either or neither case, I am lost, and would be grateful for two things (1) a straight-forward proof and (2) a separate bit of insight/intuition that can motivate my understanding of the proof.

Comment: I would start with a specific case.  Can you prove it for $f(x)=x$?  The resulting $g=g_\varepsilon$ is going to look like the Cantor-lebesgue function, but arbitrarily close to the graph of $f$.  For the case of general $f$, use the _uniform continuity_ of $f$ to finish up...

Comment: FYI, this result was originally proved in [Luzin's famous 1915 Masters thesis](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/93436/49593). See Lemma 2.3 on p. 21 of [*Luzin's work on the metric theory of functions*](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1070/RM1985v040n03ABEH003588) by Petr Lavrent'evich Ul'yanov [**Russian Mathematical Surveys** 40 #3 (1985), pp. 15-77].

Comment: That's a good example. Does that mean you interpret the problem as not precisely saying $\forall \varepsilon$, but rather for some fixed $\varepsilon$?

Comment: *Does that mean you interpret the problem ...* --- The function $f$ and the number $\varepsilon$ are first chosen and fixed. After this, the function $g$ is defined. Thus, $g$ is allowed to depend on $f$ and $\varepsilon.$ In fact, it's not difficult to see that $g$ cannot be independent of either $f$ or $\varepsilon.$

Comment: That solves it for me. Thanks to all respondents!

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, I suppose one way would be to $\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$-approximate $f$ using a polygonal path (i.e. piecewise linear, with a finite number of "pieces"), which you can do by uniform continuity of $f,$ then use scaled and/or translated and/or rotated versions of the Cantor-Lebesgue function to $\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$-approximate each of the linear segments, making sure that the finitely many versions of the Cantor-Lebesgue function "join together" so as to form a continuous function. For "function", make sure none of the rotated versions fail the vertical line test!

Comment: I'm sure you're right; I was unwittingly forcing an interpretation of the problem that simply isn't in the plain reading of the text. Now that you have made he matter plain to me, the problem is no longer troubling. Thanks again, truly.